# Migrating from Objective-C to Swift and deleting already converted Objective-C files

Tags: objective-c, swift

How do you delete the already migrated Objective-C files that are inside of the Xcode project? The function main.m can access the Swift functions, but must I keep the .h and .m files that have been converted to its Swift equivalent?

I was able to convert the Objective-C class into a Swift class. Then I accessed the Swift functions from main.m.

Below are the .h and .m files:

```
@interface SimpleClassObject:NSObject

-(void) IntVariableSent:(int)x;
-(int) MethodReturn: (int)y;

@end;
```

Below is the .m file

```
@implementation SimpleClassObject

-(void) IntVariableSent:(int)x
 {
     NSLog(@"The value of x = %d was passed into this Objective C method", x);
 }

-(int) MethodReturn: (int)y
{
    int multiply = 3;

    multiply *= y;
    NSLog(@"An integer was passed to MethodReturn of y = %d", y);

    return multiply;
}

@end
```

Below is the Swift class:

```
class SimpleClassObject2: NSObject {
    func intVariableSent(_ x: Int) {
        print("The value of x = \(x) was passed into a Swift function")
    }

    @objc func methodReturn(_ y: Int) -> Int {
        var multiply: Int = 3
        multiply *= y
        print("An integer was passed to methodReturn of y = \(y)")
        return multiply
    }
}
```

Below is main.m

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int valueReturnedFromFunction;

        SimpleClassObject2 *swftObj = [[SimpleClassObject2 alloc]init];
        [swftObj passNothingReturnNothing];
        [swftObj intVariableSent:90];
        valueReturnedFromFunction  = (int)[swftObj methodReturn:80];
        printf("\n%d value using Swift class\n\n", valueReturnedFromFunction);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't need the class .h and .m, why can't you simply delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the Objective C file, after it was disassociated from the Xcode project. Thus MikeIOSMike was correct. Thank you MikeIOSMike for your response